# How are iOS apps geo-restricted on the Apple App Store? Is this something decided by the developer, or is it decided by Apple?

Tags: developer-program

How are apps geo-restricted on the Apple App Store?

Can the developer choose which countries his/her app will be available in when he submits this to the Apple App Store? Or is this something decided by Apple themselves? If the former, how does he specify this? If the latter, how does Apple decide which countries an app will be available in?

Comment: Can you define geo restricted apps? Is this about using location after you purchase the app or about which legal region / stores allow purchase of an arbitrary app?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a great while since I've had anything in the App Store, but yes, the developer chooses what countries to make his app available in. It's not a decision made by Apple themselves, unless there's some sort of regulatory restriction on a single or category of apps in a particular country.

When the developer goes to publish submit their application before review by Apple, there should be a section that allows the developer to specify in which countries they'd like to make the app available for download.

Answer (score 0):

Developers must choose which regions they make an app for sale. They have banking and tax and potentially legal agreements to review.

Apple reviews and also has a regulatory position and may pass on region specific guidance or have special reviews in some cases.